# overheating when using ubuntu14.04

Tags: power-management

I installed ubuntu 14.04 in my asus intel i5 laptop. The laptop is heating up to a high temperature quickly which I never seen when using the windows. Can anybody give a solution?

Comment: It could be that Ubuntu doesn't recognize your graphics card and is in software rendering mode. That would cause your CPU to overheat much quicker

Answer (score 0):

Install Tlp A power saving tool:-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp


sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

If You using GPU (Nvidia/AMD) change prime profile Intel Mode 
[image]